# In my Vite/React project, I'm having trouble implementing an environment variable for my Openweather API key

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, environment-variables, vite

I have an `.env` file in my root folder of the project.
I checked the API key and it is correct and I used the actual key in the URL instead of `process.env.API_KEY` and it fetched the data correctly

I'm using VITE and in my `server.js` file I've got this line:

```
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
```

This is my function for getting the data:

```js
const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY;
const getData = (city) => {
    if (!city) return;
    const apiURL =
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
      city +
      "&units=metric&appid=" +
      apiKey;
    axios
      .get(apiURL)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Response: ", res.data);
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
      });
  };
```

I'm trying to implement environment variables in my weather component in order to hide my API key. I want to fetch the weather details using the API key from my `.env` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use `import.meta.env.<YOUR_API_KEY>`

please refer to this, https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Hope it helped

Comment: I had tried it, but it didn't work...

Comment: long shot, but do you have this in your vite.config `/// <reference types="vite/client" />` ?